# Remove SQL71502 warning for unresolved reference to JSON data

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Project in Jet Brains rider. When I go to build the project I am getting the following error message:

> spChartPixelReplot.sql(145, 91): [SQL71502] SqlProcedure: [dbo].[spChartPixelReplot] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to one or more unnamed objects or any of the following objects: ::[value], [dbo].[Device].[channelIDs]::[value] or [dbo].[DeviceChannel].[channelIDs]::[value].

My DDL for the sp is as follows:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  [dbo].[spChartPixelReplot]  
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spChartPixelReplot]  
    @json       NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS

   

/******************** 
* Declare Variables *
*********************/
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE
    @ErrorLine                  INT,
    @ErrorState                 INT,
    @ErrorNumber                INT,
    @ErrorMessage               NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ErrorSeverity              INT,
    @ErrorProcedure             NVARCHAR(200),
    @RC                         INT,
    @dynamicSQL                 NVARCHAR(MAX),
  
    @DownloadTableName          NVARCHAR(100),
    @MainLevelDataTableName     NVARCHAR(100),
    @TimeElapsedSecs            DECIMAL(15, 6),
    @GroupLevel                 INT = 0,
    @recordcount                INT,                    
    @ReadingStartDate           DATETIME2,
    @ReadingEndDate             DATETIME2,
    @PixelCount                 INT = 512,
    --@msg                      NVARCHAR(3000),
    --@Procname                 NVARCHAR(200),
    --@Arguments                    NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CreatedByUser              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,

    @BeginningDate              DATETIME2,                 
    @EndDate                    DATETIME2,                 
    @SerialNumber               NVARCHAR(60),              
    @ChannelID                  NVARCHAR(10),              
    @VinCounter                 INT,                       
    @VinMaxCounter              INT,                       
    @DeviceChannelID            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,          
    @DeviceID                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL     

  
   DECLARE @Channel_Info TABLE
   (
            [ID]                                                INT  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            ChannelId                                           INT,        
            DeviceChannelID                                     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
            DownloadTableName                                   NVARCHAR(100),
            [ReadingTrimDate]                                   DATETIME2(7) NULL
   
    )
       

/*********************** 
* Initialise Variables *
***********************/
           
            SELECT
                @DeviceID               = D.DeviceID,                       
                @SerialNumber           = device.SerialNumber,              
                @BeginningDate          = Device.BeginningDate,             
                @EndDate                = Device.EndDate                    
              FROM
                OPENJSON(@JSON)
                         WITH
                             (
                             SerialNumber           INT             '$.SerialNumber',
                             ChannelIDs             NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.ChannelIDs' AS JSON,
                             BeginningDate          DATETIME2       '$.BeginningDate',
                             EndDate                DATETIME2       '$.EndDate',
                             Amount                 INT             '$.Amount',
                             SortOrder              NVARCHAR(30)    '$.SortOrder',
                             IncludeFirstDate       NVARCHAR(10)    '$.IncludeFirstDate'
                             ) AS device
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(ChannelIDs,'[',''),']',''),',') channelIDs
            LEFT JOIN
                Device D                                ON device.SerialNumber = D.SerialNumber
            LEFT JOIN
                dbo.DeviceChannel DC                    ON D.DeviceID   = DC.DeviceID AND channelIDs.value = DC.ChannelID
```

I have isolated it to this line

```
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(ChannelIDs,'[',''),']',''),',') channelIDs
```

This is extracting a list of channelIds from the incoming JSON

So how do I get rid of this warning; with a unresolved reference to JSON data?

Comment: i'm guessing it's cause you have channelIds as alias name as well as part of openjson as column name. Perhaps you can rename the channelIDs alias to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid SQL but I can repro in SSDT.

Unfortunately the version of the parser used in SSDT/SQL Package doesn't have full fidelity with the one used in the actual database engine and sometimes raises spurious warnings.

There is no ambiguity here because it is not valid to call a `.value` property on a `JSON` column. The following does execute without errors although looks a little weird

```
SELECT *
FROM  OPENJSON('{"ChannelIDs" : [1,2,3]}')
            WITH(ChannelIDs   NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.ChannelIDs' AS json) AS device
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(ChannelIDs,'[',''),']',''),',') channelIDs
where channelIDs /*The column*/ = '[1,2,3]'  AND channelIDs.value /*The split value*/ = '1'
```

It also looks suspect that you are using `STRING_SPLIT` here - you can use `OPENJSON` to split a JSON array

```
SELECT channelIDs, value
FROM  OPENJSON('{"ChannelIDs" : [1,2,3]}')
            WITH(ChannelIDs   NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.ChannelIDs' AS json) AS device
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(channelIDs) channelIDs
where channelIDs /*The column*/ = '[1,2,3]'  AND channelIDs.value /*The split value*/ = '1'
```

Regarding the spurious warnings maybe the SSDT parser code gets confused here because `XML` columns do have a [`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) method.

Rename the alias of the table expression with the `STRING_SPLIT`

```
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(ChannelIDs,'[',''),']',''),',') channelIDs
```

So it doesn't have the same name as the `ChannelIDs` column

**Squiggle**

[image]

**No Squiggle**

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys 

That worked for me .. changing the  name of the Alias in the String_Split Expression.  I have also applied the OPENJSON to split a JSON array